# How to make the three images apear inline?

Tags: css

Chevy Camaro MSRP: From $25,000 Horsepower: 275 to 650 hp MPG: Up to 22 city / 31 highway Curb weight: 3,354 to 4,113 lbs Engine: 2.0 L 4-cylinder, 3.6 L V6, 6.2 L V8 And if you want the convertible version you pay $35000+

```
         <div class="links"><a> <img src="mustang.jpg" width="200" height="150"white-space= "nowrap"><span> Ford Mustang MSRP: From $26,395
                    Horsepower: 310 to 480 hp
                    MPG: Up to 21 city / 32 highway
                    Curb weight: 3,532 to 3,825 lbs
                    Engine: 2.3 L 4-cylinder, 5.0 L V8
                    For the convisrtable version the price starts at $31000</span></a>

             </div>
        <div class="links"> <a> <img src="challenger.jpg" width="200" height="150"white-space= "nowrap"><span>Dodge Challenger MSRP: From $27,845
                    Horsepower: 305 to 797 hp
                    MPG: Up to 19 city / 30 highway
                    Curb weight: 3,894 to 4,448 lbs
                    Engine: 3.6 L V6, 5.7 L V8, 6.2 L V8, 6.4 L V8
                    There are other models of this specific car, and the price can go as high as $37000</span></a>
             </div>
```

Comment: I found my mistake, all classes are named the same and the css I had in place wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
 <div class="column"  ><a> <img src="mustang.jpg" width=100% white-space= "nowrap"><span> Ford Mustang MSRP: From $26,395
                    Horsepower: 310 to 480 hp
                    MPG: Up to 21 city / 32 highway
                    Curb weight: 3,532 to 3,825 lbs
                    Engine: 2.3 L 4-cylinder, 5.0 L V8
                    For the convisrtable version the price starts at $31000</span></a>

             </div>
        <div class="column"> <a> <img src="challenger.jpg" width=100% white-space= "nowrap"><span>Dodge Challenger MSRP: From $27,845
                    Horsepower: 305 to 797 hp
                    MPG: Up to 19 city / 30 highway
                    Curb weight: 3,894 to 4,448 lbs
                    Engine: 3.6 L V6, 5.7 L V8, 6.2 L V8, 6.4 L V8
                    There are other models of this specific car, and the price can go as high as $37000</span></a>
             </div>  
             <div class="column"> <a> <img src="challenger.jpg" width=100% white-space= "nowrap"><span>Dodge Challenger MSRP: From $27,845
                    Horsepower: 305 to 797 hp
                    MPG: Up to 19 city / 30 highway
                    Curb weight: 3,894 to 4,448 lbs
                    Engine: 3.6 L V6, 5.7 L V8, 6.2 L V8, 6.4 L V8
                    There are other models of this specific car, and the price can go as high as $37000</span></a>
             </div>  
             </div>
```